# Custom Post Type Displaying only one latest post In Admin

Tags: wordpress

I have added 5-6 custom post type in wordpress and all others working well but only one custom post type have issues and it shows only one  latest post in admin but there is 18 post of that post type. At top it displays like this
All (18) | Published (18)

and also in front end shows all 18 post so problems on admin area only

anyone have any idea about this?

Thank you
Hridaya Ghimire

Comment: Are you sure the logged user have permission to see all the posts in wp-admin?

Comment: yes  have permission because logged in user is administrator. And all other custom post type works perfectly  except that one .

Comment: fixed this problem. There was a function in functios.php file that function cause the issue.